# Android : IllegalStateException: Couldn't init cursor window when executing getThumbail

Tags: android, image, cursor, illegalstateexception

I have a stack trace saying illegal state exception :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't init cursor window
>   at android.database.CursorWindow.native_init(Native Method)
>   at android.database.CursorWindow.(CursorWindow.java:63)
>   at android.database.CursorWindow.(CursorWindow.java:80)
>   at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:437)
>   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:264)
>   at android.provider.MediaStore$InternalThumbnails.getThumbnail(MediaStore.java:387)
>   at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Thumbnails.getThumbnail(MediaStore.java:788)
>   at com.topicshow.threading.ImageThread.loadingImageFromID(ImageThread.java:56)
>   at com.topicshow.threading.ImageThread.run(ImageThread.java:52)

The function loadingImageFromID is a function inside my handler class where my thread will sendMessage to the handler and the handler will call this function.

```
    private void loadingImageFromID () {
    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
            mContext.getContentResolver(), 
            mNativeID, 
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, 
            new Options());

    if (!mExpired) 
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos); 
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

        Message msg = new Message();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putByteArray("IMAGE", bitmapdata);
        msg.setData(bundle);
```

This is the code to fetch the image data from mediastore.

```
public void loadGalleryToAdapter(int width, String bucketID) {


    Cursor thumbnailCursor = MediaStore.Images.Media.query(getContext().getContentResolver(), MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
            new String [] { 
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_ADDED
            },
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID + " IN (" + bucketID + ")",
            null,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC"
    );

    GalleryCursorAdapter adapter = new GalleryCursorAdapter(getContext(), thumbnailCursor, width);  
    setAdapter(adapter); 

}
```

Does anyone know what is going on. The loadGalleryToAdapter i am not sure is it the start point since the stacktrace doesn't have that information.... The thread was executed within the adapter.

Comment: do you need a certain permission for MediaStore?

Comment: what kind of permission? i have this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"

Comment: no idea, just seems like some type of MediaStore error